# note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq Rust

Tags: rust-cargo

il" "-ldl" "-lutil" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `actix-todo`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing the `postgresql-libs` package. Install it using your systems package manager.

Comment: So simple the answer turns out to be. Helped me alot.

Comment: I could not find postgresql-libs to install

Answer (score 2):

For me I needed to install `libpq-dev`. You can install it on linux like this:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```